# Indexing static page content for internal site search

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cognitive-search

I want to index static page content within Azure Search (alongside dynamic content) and am trying to figure out the best way to handle it. I'd like to avoid storing all of the static content in the database. My thought right now is to pull all text into resource files and have my index function pull content from those. Is there a better option available or a recommended practice that I'm not aware of? There's surprisingly little available on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives to storing your static content in a database:

1. You can store (and serve) static pages directly from the blob storage, and use [Azure Search blob indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage) for indexing.
2. You can use an HTML crawler to crawl and index your site. For example, you can use [AzureSearchCrawler tool](https://github.com/thomas11/AzureSearchCrawler) developed by an engineer on our team.